# Keyboard ignores first key pressed on Manjaro Gnome

Tags: keyboard-event

After one or two minutes, the first key I press is ignored. Which key doesn’t matter, Meta, Alt, Space, Shift, numbers, letters. It is as if the keyboard goes on a dormant mode after about 90 seconds or so, then the first key pressed wakes it up.

Why?

I can’t find anything addressing this, and it seems somewhat unbelievable.

I have been running Manjaro Gnome for the last several months, reinstalled, swapped keyboards with other machines, installed the same USB installer on other machines without duplicating the problem, enabled and disabled Wayland running X11, and the problem persists on this one machine with Linux.

I'm dual-booting to Windows 10 on the same machine with OEM registered Windows license keys and Windows has no problem like this at all.

I’m running Gnome 44.1 Linux 6.1.31-2-MANJARO with X11 on a 4th gen i7-4790 x8, ASUS board "All Series" Firmware 0603, and AMD Radeon™ RX 470 GPU, with 16 GB of RAM.

But, I don’t know where to look or how to check to see what is causing this. My only guesses are: Arch, Gnome, Xorg.

Where do I look?

How do I fix?

Comment: Just to double-check: it's wired keyboards, right? I can totally believe that a wireless keyboard, especially a cheap one, would suspend and eat the first keypress, and/or some power saving setting would power down "inactive" wireless connections.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Wired, all stuff like that is tested. I would think its a BIOS issue, but Windows doesn't act that way.

Comment: The bios isn't involved in USB keyboards.

Comment: @MarcusMüller But, BIOS does govern the USB ports. It has rather extensive settings about the type of support given to the USB ports. It's one of those new ASUS BIOS interfaces with a mouse and drag-drop disks for boot priority and Advanced mode. Just how BIOS makes trouble with Secure Boot for Linux, it's way of handling USB ports could be interpreted by Xorg as a kind of time-out. The problem is that this only happens with keyboards. The mouse might also skip the first moved pixel and I can't notice. Mics and other tech might be too complex to be affected. But, no such articles online.

Comment: The bios might be involved with the initialization of the controllers, but it is very much out of the way during operation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So while there may be different BIOS settings for initializing USB controllers, none of that should matter for this. It's a head scratcher.

Comment: Are there any commands to run to watch the activity of the keyboard in a terminal, like a lower-level equivalent of `dconf watch /`?